# How to automatically sum columns datas of a grouped row subset with common attributes (excel csv spreadsheet)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, csv, spreadsheet

I have a big csv file (one million rows) I imported in excel.
I have to do a simple operation, easy to be done manually, but I should do it for thousands groupings so I am looking for an automated system to do it.

I try to explain:
I grouped the rows that have the the firsts 2 common column datas, the ones selected in the example picture (with attributes 6 and 0101). I call them source rows.

I need to create a new row that has the same 2 values in the first 2 columns (6 and 0101); the other values, in this new row, must be the sum of each column of the source rows (should result 1,1,2,0,0,2,0,1.... in the example).

The source rows selected in the picture **should be then DELETED**.

The procedure should then continue for the next groupings (7 and 0101), (8 and 0101) and so on... down to the end.

I am not so good with excel (or other software) to make the operation automatically.
I would like to know if there is a simple method in excel or if it could be done by a bash script o loading the csv file in a database software and elaborating it and extracting a new csv file. Any simple solution would be interesting.

I hope my English is understandable,
thank you very much for help!

PS: please remember I am a newbie... easiest is better! :)

[example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pv80X.png)

Comment: You could create a new column where you concatenate your first two columns. Then create a pivot table, where your ROWS is that new concat column, and your columns are a sum of your columns.

Comment: Hello, thank you. Ok, is this something that I can do in excel? I try to understand how it works googling for concatenation and pivot table.

Comment: Seems like it would be a straightforward task in Power Query.  `Get Data from CSV / Group: Select the first two columns, then Aggregate by Sum`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365

To use Power Query

- `Data => Get&Transform => from Text/CSV` and select the file => Transform
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the path in the second line of code
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the path name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm
- The way it is coded should adapt to any number of columns

**M Code**

```
let

//Read in CSV document and convert to table
    csvSource = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\users\ron\desktop\test.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    Source = Table.PromoteHeaders(csvSource,[PromoteAllScalars = true]),

//type first two columns as Text and
//type all columns after first two as integers (but could change to floats if need be
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,
        List.Transform(List.FirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),2), each {_, Text.Type}) &
        List.Transform(List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),2), each {_, Int64.Type})),

//create dynamic list of Sum functions for the Table.Group command
//we will sum all columns except the first two
//so need to create a list of a sum function for each column in the table
colsToSum= List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"),2),
sumFunction = List.Transform(colsToSum, 
        (C) => {C, each List.Sum(Table.Column(_, C)), type number}),

//Group on first two columns and aggregate with Sum
groupSum = Table.Group(#"Changed Type",
                List.FirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"),2), 
                sumFunction)

in
    groupSum
```

**Source**  *as csv document*

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
1,0101,0,1,0
1,0101,0,2,1
1,0101,0,3,0
1,0101,1,4,1
2,0101,0,5,0
2,0101,0,6,1
2,0102,1,7,0
2,0102,0,8,1
3,0101,0,1,0
3,0101,0,2,1
3,0101,0,3,0
3,0101,1,4,1
4,0101,0,5,0
4,0101,0,6,1
4,0101,0,7,0
```

**Results**
[image]

Comment: Thank you. This seems exactly all I need! I wrote excel but I have libreoffice and it seems it has not this "power query". I found this add-in for libreoffice that maybe could work as power query? https://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/decroise

Comment: @James I don't understand. If you don't want an Excel type solution, why use that as a tag?  If you want only a Libre Office solution, you should mention that in your question and use that as a tag.  I suggest you edit your question, tags and I will delete my answer.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. At the beginning I supposed the solution was simple and common for excel and calc so I putted just one spreadsheet. Now I understand it was stupid. Anyway your solution is great, I will try it when I have a PC with excel. Thank you very much. I only need to elaborate those datas, if I need excel I will find a pc with excel installed :)

Comment: @James OK.  If this works for you when you get a chance with a Windows machine, I would appreciate it if you would **Accept** the answer, or post back with any issues.

Comment: Ron, ok, I will let you know as soon as possible